# Is load faster than dlmread for reading 3 to 4 GB files?

Tags: matlab, load

I have several files each around 3 to 4GB, I can read them with either function, but I'm sure if there is any advantages for load or dlmread, are there?

Comment: Is there a reason why not to read binary `fread` ? (I remember it was the fastest way back then)

Comment: This is something you can easily benchmark, no? Either way, I agree with @bla that it's better to pre-process these files by loading them once and then saving them in some binary format (e.g., `.mat`), which should be both smaller and faster to read. Further gains are possible if the storage precision of each variable is determined according to the actual values (i.e., there's no reason to store integers as `double` if  `uint8` can also do the job).